# Grails 3 (GORM) datasource properties not loading from Spring Cloud Config Server

Tags: grails, spring-cloud, grails-3.0

I am trying to use Spring Cloud Config Server to externalize my Grails 3  (personnel) application configuration, but I cannot seem to set the dataSource properties.

Currently, I can load other properties (`sample.message`) into my Grails 3 (personnel) application and retrieve them using `grailsApplication.config.sample.message` without an issue. And hitting the REST endpoint on the Config Server (`localhost:8888/personnel/master`) is showing the configuration information I want, so I'm a bit confused.

I have tried each of the following in my `personnel.properties` file in my Git repo:

```
datasource.user=example
datasource.password=example

grails.datasource.user=example
grails.datasource.password=example

spring.datasource.user=example
spring.datasource.password=example
```

But none of them work. I continue to see error messages saying `sa@localhost (using password: no)` suggesting that the datasource properties, in particular, are not working.

I know it is possible with `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`, so I'm wondering:

1. Is it possible with GORM?
2. If so, do I need to manually create the datasource bean?
3. What property names do I use `datasource.user`, `grails.datasource.user`, `spring.datasource.user`, etc?

Answer (score 1):

After Shashank's edit, I realized that it was an issue with my property settings. `datasource` should have been `dataSource` and `user` should be `username`.  Once those corrections were made, the application (personnel) worked perfectly. So,

1. Yes it is possible.
2. No, you don't need to create the bean manually
3. Property names are:

**personnel.properties**

```
dataSource.username=example
dataSource.password=example
dataSource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/personnel
```